# IIS 8 Failed Request Tracing rules Disappearing

Tags: .net, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I have added failed request tracing to IIS 8 on my Windows 2012 server a few months ago.  I added one rule per site which logged perfectly.  I then noticed a few weeks ago it stopped and looking at the tracing the rules were gone completely.  I added them back, it worked for a few days, and now they are gone again.  Anyone have any advice on why this is happening or how to fix this?  I made the rules through the iis wizard. Not sure if there are any config settings i can set?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue. I discovered that when setting the trace rules in IIS, like many other settings they are stored directly on the `web.config`-file. But every time I published, my `web.config`-file was replaced with the version in my solution. So on publish the trace rules were gone.

The solution was to move the portion of the `web.config`-file which was storing the trace rules back into my solution. They were then included on publish.